# Median depending on other variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I want to calculate median conditionally, say separately for men and women in a sex variable as an example. I would like to use the modification of one of the following two alternative codes provided here http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/median as the fastest method for calculating median.

**Alternative 1**

```
DECLARE @c BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.EvenRows); 

SELECT AVG(1.0 * val) 
FROM (
    SELECT val FROM dbo.EvenRows
     ORDER BY val
     OFFSET (@c - 1) / 2 ROWS
     FETCH NEXT 1 + (1 - @c % 2) ROWS ONLY
) AS x;
```

**Alternative 2**

```
SELECT @Median = AVG(1.0 * val)
FROM
(
    SELECT o.val, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.val), c.c
    FROM dbo.EvenRows AS o
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.EvenRows) AS c
) AS x
WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2);
```

Where to put `GROUP` statement? Can someone advise me how to make a function with parameters `MEDIAN(ColumnToCalculateMedian, ColumnContaingSex)`

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? If it's 2012 or above you can get median using PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231327.aspx which has examples that include grouping.

Comment: There's a link in the comments to a [follow-up article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/calculating-the-median-value-within-a-partitioned-set-using-t-sql/), which discusses this scenario.